# Convert a string to binary and then count the number of unset bits

Tags: c, binary, bit, bit-shift

In C, I want to take a string (from the user), scan it by bit, and print out the number of unset bit. The string length will not be greater than 127. I also want to exclude the null character that is at the end of the string. For the string "hi", my output is 25 even though it should be 9. Not sure what I am doing incorrectly.

```
int unset(char* s){
    size_t len = strlen(s);
    char *bin = malloc(len*8);
    char x;

    bin[0] = '\0';

    for(int i=0; i<=len; ++i) { //convert the string to binary
        if (s[i] != '\0'){ 
            x = s[i];
            for(int j=7; j>=0; --j){
                if((x & (1 << j)) == 0) {
                    strcat(bin,"0");
                }
                else {
                    strcat(bin,"1");
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
    int n = strtol(bin, NULL, 2);
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<INT_SIZE; i++){ //count the unset bits
        if((n & 1) == 0){
            ++count;
        }
        n >>= 1;
    }
    return count;
}

int main{
    char sen[128];
    printf("String: ");
    scanf("%s", sen);

    printf("%d", unset(sen));
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: You remember that strings are null-terminated, but you forget that `strlen` does not count the terminator. So a string of length `len` need space for `len + 1` characters. Or a string of `len * 8` needs space for `(len * 8) + 1` characters.

Comment: On that note (about terminators) the loop `for(int i=0; i<=len; ++i)` will include the terminator, which I doubt you want to use. You need to change the condition to `i < len` to not include the terminator.

Comment: And on a different note, you allocate memory using `malloc`, but you never `free` it. That leads to a memory leak.

Comment: Finally, there's no need to convert the string containing the ones and zeros. In fact there's no need to even *have* the temporary `bin` string. Just go through the bytes of the input string, and count the zero-bits in each byte. Basically `if((x & (1 << j)) == 0) { count++; }` in the first loop.

Comment: If you have to do this repeatedly, consider constructing a table that contains precomputed bit counts for each possible value.  Then just index that by each character in your string and take the sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistakes are:

- You are counting zeros of `00000000 00000000 01011000 01101001`. (only 2 characters is read, but it seems you are counting among full `int`)
- 127 byte will be too long to fit in `int`.
- The buffer assigned to `bin` has no room for terminating null-character, but `strcat()` will add that. Therefore out-of-bound write will be performed.
- `(void)` is missing after `int main`.
- Required headers are missing.

Instead of converting strings to binary string, you can count bits in characters directly:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int unset(const char* s){
    int count = 0;
    while(*s != '\0'){
        for(int i=7; i>=0; --i){
            if((*s & (1 << i)) == 0) count++;
        }
        s++;
    }
    return count;
}

int main(void){
    char sen[128];
    printf("String: ");
    scanf("%127s", sen);

    printf("%d", unset(sen));
    return 0; 
}
```